# Why isn't my Greasemonkey script updating?

Tags: greasemonkey, auto-update, tampermonkey

I've got a Greasemonkey script for Firefox. The script includes this meta-block and some lines of code.

I want to update my script on the server and then automatically update the browser's scripts. The `requireSecureUpdates` option is off.
What am I doing wrong?

My 1.meta.js

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name     Ibood autosubmit 
// @include  https://*.ibood.com/* 
// @include  http://*.ibood.com/* 
// @include  * 
// @version  1.1 
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js 
// @grant    GM_addStyle 
// @downloadURL http://www.tipsvoorbesparen.nl/1.user.js
// @updateURL http://www.tipsvoorbesparen.nl/1.meta.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Currently, your `1.meta.js` is:

   ```
       // ==UserScript== 
       // @name     Ibood autosubmit 
       // @include  https://*.ibood.com/* 
       // @include  http://*.ibood.com/* 
       // @include  * 
       // @version  1.7
       // @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js 
       // @grant    GM_addStyle 
       // @downloadURL http://www.tipsvoorbesparen.nl/1.user.js
       // @updateURL http://www.tipsvoorbesparen.nl/1.meta.js
       // ==/UserScript==
   ```

   Note the leading spaces?

   Greasemonkey cannot handle leading spaces for its [Metadata Block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) due to a design limitation<sup>1</sup>.
2. The current script version seems to be 1.8, but the meta file has version 1.7.

~~~~~
For small scripts, that you host on your own website, don't even bother with the `@updateURL` setting.  That's there mainly to conserve bandwidth, especially on sites like [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/).

With no `@updateURL` setting, Greasemonkey will just use/check whatever's set by `@downloadURL`.  This saves you extra maintenance work (and possible SNAFU's like this one).

Finally, on an unrelated note, don't use `@include  *`!
Using `@include *`:

1. Slows down your browser
2. Can cause unwanted side effects
3. Causes conscientious users to refuse to install your script.

---

<sup>1</sup>.  Specifically, this bit in the GM source file, `parseScript.js`:

```
var gAllMetaRegexp = new RegExp(
    '^// ==UserScript==([\\s\\S]*?)^// ==/UserScript==', 'm');
```

Comment: when you say don't use include you don't say what to use. did you mean to use match instead include?

Comment: @erm3nda, I said don't use `@include *`. That `*` makes a big difference. Yes, it's good to use `@match`, or you can use something like `@include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*`

Comment: Oh, you say `@include *` LITERALLY. You're right, that's the really wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

If the script is working, then there's not likely a problem with your meta block, EXCEPT, you need to use a valid **HTTPS** source to enable updating.

Reference
http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40downloadURL

Comment: HTPS is required only if the `Require secure updates` option is checked. (Yes, it is checked by default on new Greasemonkey installations.) Also note that it was proved that the metadata block *was* faulty in the `*.meta.js` file. So that part of this answer is wrong.